# Error in using "mapvalues" in R since my data does not have matching element

Tags: r, bar-chart

The codes below is done in R:

```
library(dplyr)

C=cbind(Mydata$item1C,Mydata$item2C, Mydata$item3C, Mydata$item4C, Mydata$item5C, 
        Mydata$item6C, Mydata$item7C, Mydata$item8C, Mydata$item9C,Mydata$item10C, 
        Mydata$item11C,Mydata$item12C, Mydata$item13C, Mydata$item14C,
        Mydata$item15C, Mydata$item16C, Mydata$item17C, ydata$item18C)

C <- mapvalues(C,from = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), to = c("Strongly \n disagree","Disagree",
    "Somewhat \n disagree","Neither agree \n nor disagree","Somewhat \n agree",
     "Agree","Strongly \n agree"))`
```

> The following `from` values were not present in `x`: 1

You can see that I have an error up there. I am aware that this error due to the fact that I do not have any 1's in my data. However, I would like to keep that and show that I have 0 people under this category. So, I was wondering if there is any way to fix that at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set the same factor levels for all columns. Unfortunately you don't provide sample data so I'll generate a small sample dataset to illustrate

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)    

set.seed(2018)
C <- cbind.data.frame(
    item1 = sample(1:7, 10, replace = T),
    item2 = sample(1:7, 10, replace = T))


# Ensure the same factor levels for all columns
C[] <- lapply(C, factor, levels = 1:7)


# Map values; note that `mapvalues` takes a vector as first argument (not a data.frame)
C[] <- sapply(
    C,
    mapvalues,
    from = 1:7,
    to = c(
        "Strongly \n disagree","Disagree", "Somewhat \n disagree",
        "Neither agree \n nor disagree","Somewhat \n agree",
        "Agree","Strongly \n agree"))
#        item1                         item2
#1           Somewhat \n disagree          Somewhat \n disagree
#2  Neither agree \n nor disagree             Somewhat \n agree
#3           Strongly \n disagree             Strongly \n agree
#4                       Disagree             Somewhat \n agree
#5  Neither agree \n nor disagree                         Agree
#6           Somewhat \n disagree             Somewhat \n agree
#7              Somewhat \n agree                      Disagree
#8           Strongly \n disagree Neither agree \n nor disagree
#9              Strongly \n agree                         Agree
#10 Neither agree \n nor disagree                         Agree
```

**Note that `mapvalues` takes a `vector` (or `factor`) as first argument (not a `data.frame`), so we need to use `sapply` (or `lapply`) to loop over the columns of `C`.**